# How do I include appsettings.json configuration settings in a nuget package?

Tags: json, asp.net-core, nuget, .net-core

I am running .net core 1.1, nuget 3.5, and hosting packages on VS team services.

I looked into transformations here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations,

But I need a solution for json files, not config files.

I read that you can use an install.ps1 script to include the file, but I also read that install.ps1 is deprecated.

What is the current method for including json configuration files in a nuget package?

Comment: It would be copied automatically to `content` package's subfolder if you set `Build Action: Content` and `Copy to output directory` file properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `<files>` node in the `.nuspec` file. Example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#adding-a-readme-and-other-files):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
    <!-- ... -->
    </metadata>
    <files>
    <!-- Add a readme -->
    <file src="readme.txt" target="" />

    <!-- Add files from an arbitrary folder that's not necessarily in the project -->
    <file src="..\..\SomeRoot\**\*.*" target="" />
    </files>
</package>
```